# Program skipping input and crashes without reason

Tags: c, function, codeblocks

ok so if fixed it up and me it presentable( im using codebloks btw ), in the getinfo function after age is entered it prints the statement to get the gender then the statement to get the other persons name without letting me input(it seems to just skip that part) and if i choose to just continue it will crash

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getinfo (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count){
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y < count; y++){
        nam[y] = malloc(30);
        printf ("What is the student's name?\t");
        scanf ("%s", &nam[y]);
        printf ("\nWhat is the students age?\t");
        scanf ("%d", &ag[y]);
        printf ("\nwhat is the students gender, M/F:\t");
        scanf ("%c", &gender[y]);
    }
}

void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char* gender[], int count){
    int largest = 0, y, eldest =0 ;
    for(y = 0; y < count; y++){
       if (ag[y] > eldest){
           largest = ag[y];
           eldest = y;
       }
    }
    printf ("The eldest student is:\t%s", nam[eldest]);
    printf ("\nGender:\t%c", gender[eldest]);
    printf ("\nWith an age of:\t%d", ag[eldest]);
}

int main (){
    int amount, y;
    printf("How many students are you admitting?\t");
    scanf ("%d", &amount);

    if (amount > 50){
        printf("Too many students!");
    }else{
        char *name[50];
        int age[50];
        char gender[50];
        getinfo(name, age, gender, amount);
        findeldest(name, age, gender, amount);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Using one will give you a clear idea of why and where this program is crashing.

Answer (score 3):

In `getinfo()` function `&` in from of `nam` is wrong:

```
scanf ("%s", &nam[y]);
             ^  remove it not need
```

like

```
scanf ("%s", nam[y]);
```

next: third argument to `findeldest()` should be `char`

```
void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char* gender[], int count)
                                           ^ remove *
```

like

```
void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
scanf ("%c", &gender[y]);
```

with

```
scanf (" %c", &gender[y]);
```

Also, the parameters for findeldest are not correct.
Change

```
void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char* gender[], int count){
```

to

```
void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count){
```

**EDIT**
Change

```
scanf ("%s", &nam[y]);
```

to

```
scanf ("%s", nam[y]);
```

Comment: it still crashes when i reach the find eldest funstion

Comment: "It still crashes" is too vague. What error do you get? Learn to provide relevant information..

Comment: like the description says it doesnt give a reason or explaination it just says program name.exe has stopped working

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: main.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 513afd64
  Fault Module Name: msvcrt.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.7601.17744
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4eeaf722
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000d193
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
there is this though i doubt it helps though

Comment: im still getting the same error

Comment: After the edit in the answer? i.e. after changing `scanf ("%s", &nam[y]);` to `scanf ("%s", nam[y]);`

Comment: i got it down now. removing th '&' really worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following changes:

**1: Change:**

```
void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char* gender[], int count)
```

To

```
void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count)
```

**2: Change:**

```
scanf ("%s", &nam[y]);
```

to

```
scanf ("%s", nam[y]);
```

**3: Change:**

```
scanf ("%c", &gender[y]);
```

To

```
scanf ("%c%*c", &gender[y]);
```

*Although its better to use getch().*

**4: Free Allocated memory:**

Add this code before system("pause");

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < amount ; i++ )
    free( name[i] );
```

*Add int i; after char gender[50]; if compile as c source.*